# How to move/copy a file to a sub-directory using awk in shell scripting

Tags: awk

Take a look at this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXo5s.png).

Here I have tried to check whether the value of `P` is `<90` and if so then I want to move this file to `good` sub-directory(`good` is a sub-directory of `RF2.0` directory)...

But unfortunately it copies the entire `RF2.0` folder into the `good` sub-folder, after running this below code, which I don't want.

Here is my code:

```
for i in *.SAC
do
P=`saclhdr -USER5 $i` 
`echo $P $i|awk '{if ($1<90) print $2}'|cp -R /home/sushrat/Downloads/RFevents/RUMJ/RF2.0/$2  /home/sushrat/Downloads/RFevents/RUMJ/RF2.0/good`

done
```

Any help to solve the issue is appreciated.

Comment: please use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) as a start to identify numerous errors in your script as written.

Comment: Regarding "Take a look at this Picture." - no, a question has to include a [mcve] in **text** with concise, testable sample input, expected output, and your attempt to solve the problem yourself. No images, no links, just text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just treat `$2` in your `awk` as `$2` in `cp` command. assign output of `awk` to a variable `x` then do whatever you want with `$x` as a filename "I guess".

```
for i in *.SAC
do
P=`saclhdr -USER5 $i` 
x=`echo $P $i|awk '{if ($1<90) print $2}'` 
cp -R /home/sushrat/Downloads/RFevents/RUMJ/RF2.0/$x /home/sushrat/Downloads/RFevents/RUMJ/RF2.0/good`

done
```